# Managing UINavigationController's viewcontrollers

Tags: ios

I am trying to understand the way a navigation controller manages its 'content controllers'. I understand that a navigationController can have an 'array' of viewcontrollers, is this where I would add all controllers it would hypothetically manage? What if I need to add more or remove them? There must be alternative ways of doing this correct?

That brings me to the second part of my question, how can I switch the content controller managed by the navigation controller. I understand that I can do

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

However this is probably one of many methods. I would like an explanation of these 2 particular relationships between the navigation controller and both its content controllers and the controller that is currently seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that a navigationController can have an 'array' of
>   viewcontrollers, is this where I would add all controllers it would
>   hypothetically manage?

Yes, you can add them all there, but typically they are added one at a time when you do a push (pushViewController:animated: adds a new controller to the end of the array).

```
What if I need to add more or remove them?
```

The viewControllers array is an NSArray, so you need to create a mutable copy if you want to add or remove controllers, then use setViewControllers: and pass your mutable array to it to create the new list of controllers.

```
how can I switch the content controller managed by the navigation controller?
```

There are several ways to do this. You can use one of the pop methods to go back one, to go back to a specific controller, or to go back to the root view controller. The controller that is currently seen is the one in the topViewController property.

All these methods are clearly laid out in the UINavigationController class reference. If there's a specific one you don't understand, then ask about it.